# Trouble installing rgdal on R 3.2.3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I am using R on ubuntu 16.04. I have been trying to install the `rgdal` package. But every time I am getting the following error:

```
> install.packages('rgdal', type="source")  Installing package into
> ‘/home/arnab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘rgdal’ is not
> available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

I looked at a couple of solutions provided by people for users on ubuntu. I installed the packages `gdal-bin`, `libroj-dev`, `libgdal-dev`, `libgdal1-dev`. But even after that I am getting the same error message. I downloaded the package from CRAN and tried installing it manually by mentioning the `libpath` but that didn't work either. Incidentally I was facing similar troubles with the `rgeos` package as well, but after following recommendations for installing `libgeos-dev`, I could install `rgeos`. I have no idea what might be going wrong. (NB: I am using R 3.2.3)

Comment: Just checking: is `libroj-dev` a typo? That should be `libproj-dev` (with `p`)

Comment: Yes its a typo. I should have written libproj-dev.

Answer (score 2):

The rgdal package needs a newer R version:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.3.0)
```

so upgrading your R is the best solution. Otherwise you'll have to get an older version from the CRAN archive, but that is a sub-optimal solution.